# ¿Como añadir las series de datos en un Chart C#?

Tags: c#

Saludos a todos, estoy desarrollando graficas en C#, mi problema es que no sé como agregar las series de datos a la grafica, tal y como aparecen en Excel. Realmente lo que me interesaría es agregar algún identificador que me permita relacionar los datos mas cómodamente. Un ejemplo de como me gustaría verlos es con esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo construidos (un ejemplo) esta gráfica, he buscado en la parte de las propiedades del Chart, pero no logro encontrar la opción que me permita sean mostrados. ¿Alguna idea por favor?. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código para crear los gráficos.

```
                    <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="false" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="10" 
                            LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="10" LabelAutoFitStyle="None" Interval="1">
                            <LabelStyle Angle ="90" Font="Arial" IsEndLabelVisible ="false" />                            
                    </AxisX>

                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

Con este método relleno la serie de gráficos, es importante mencionarles que es una aplicación web.

```
 protected void ObtenerDatos(string strmes)
        {
            DataSet finalizo = new DataSet();
            DataSet no_finalizo = new DataSet();

            clsConexioncs conexion_server = new clsConexioncs();

            conexion_server.Conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDW"].ToString();

            graf_uso_dispositivo_mes.Titles.Add("Uso dispositivo mensual").Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);



            //-------------------FINALIZO TAREAS

            graf_uso_dispositivo_mes.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            graf_uso_dispositivo_mes.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            graf_uso_dispositivo_mes.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";
            graf_uso_dispositivo_mes.Series["Series1"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Podrías ayudar colocando el código con el que generas el gráfico

Answer (score 0):

la sintaxis no la recuerdo bien, pero te dejo esto a modo de ejemplo por si te sirve:

```
Series serie1 = new Series();
serie1.ToolTip = "Mi tooltip";
graf_uso_dispositivo_mes.ChartAreas.Series.Add(serie1);
```

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

yo he realizado algo semejante pero utilizando WinForms.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este código armo las series. Si te sirve de algo sería genial!

```
chartVtaMes.Series.Clear();//Limpio las series
                        foreach (DataRow i in dtBinding.Rows)
                        {
                            string[] cnl1 = { i.Field<string>("Canal")};
                            decimal[] vta1 = { i.Field<decimal>("Venta") };
                            chartVtaMes.Series.Add(new Series(i.Field<string>("Canal")));
                            chartVtaMes.Series[i.Field<string>("Canal")].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100;
                            //chartVtaMes.Series[i.Field<string>("Canal")].LabelFormat = "N2";
                            //chartVtaMes.Series[i.Field<string>("Canal")].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                            chartVtaMes.Series[i.Field<string>("Canal")].Label = "#VALY{N2}";// + Environment.NewLine + "(#PERCENT)";
                            chartVtaMes.Series[i.Field<string>("Canal")].Points.DataBindXY(cnl1, vta1);
                            chartVtaMes.Series[i.Field<string>("Canal")].LabelForeColor = Color.White;
                        }
```